# Как сохранить сообщение пользователя в нормальном регистре?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Бот сохраняет сообщение пользователя в `msg`, но вот не могу понять, везде либо `upper`, либо `lower`, а как сохранить без повышения и понижения регистра?

```py
for event in longpool.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.to_me:
            id = event.user_id
            msg = event.text.upper()

            print(msg)
```

Comment: Убрать `upper` или `lower`?

Comment: @ClarkDevlin TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: но чего то не очень понимаю почему именно это выдает

Comment: `msg = event.text`

Comment: @ClarkDevlin А я чет и забыл про них)) Напиши в ответ решение

Answer (score 0):

`msg = event.text`

Из комментариев от @ClarkDevlin

Comment: Плохая идея — копировать код из комментариев _без всяких дополнений, объяснений_, это некрасиво.

Comment: @Глеб ответ был в комментариях, подтверждать не планировал его, если даст ответ человек, который дал ответ в комментариях- подтвержу. А так возможно для людей которые столкнуться с такой проблемой будет быстрее понять что и как

Comment: @Глеб плюсом в ответе оставил чей ответ, не украл))